# Mapped Network Drives Persistently Requesting Credentials

Tags: windows-server-2008, password-management

I run a small office network with one Windows 2008 R2 DC and eight Windows 8.1 clients connecting to it. All of the machines have computer accounts on the domain and each user has an old school logon batch file that maps two shared folders with persistence enabled.

When a user logs into their workstation, the script runs without issue and maps the drives, however for some reason there's a red X over the drives themselves, and when I double click on the netshare, Windows prompts me to enter in the user credentials. When I do it opens the drive just fine. I've checked "Remember my credentials" but still I am prompted upon logging in or booting up.

When testing with two Windows 7 machines, I cannot replicate this issue.

Very likely I'm overlooking something stupidly obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does your login script look like?  And why not map the drives via GPP (group policy preferences) instead of old school?

Comment: Answering your second question first -- old habits die hard. lol. I will look into this and likely get updated with the times. Thanks for the tip.

Second: net use x: \\server_name\netshare /persistent:yes

Comment: Assuming the user's login at CTRL-ALT-DEL is the same as the credentials used on the mapping, it should work fine then.  Perhaps start the script with a `net use x: /del` line just to make sure the mapping is cleared up first.  And with a login script it isn't necessary to have `/persistent:yes` since you are running it at every login regardless.  Technically the `/persistent` flag should allow you to run it once on the clients and then delete the login script.  As long as they don't forcefully delete the mapped drive it'll show up after reboot regardless because of that parameter option.

Answer (score -1):

Apply the batch file through Logon Scripts in Group Policy Management Console